# How to properly pack an Electron Typescript project with forge-packager

Tags: typescript, electron, electron-packager

I currently have an electron project with this structure:

```
<project-name>
    build    // The build project from typescript with tsc and webpack
    nodes_modules
    src    // The application code (typescript) as well as the resources used by the app (icons, images...)
    package.json
    [vscode directories and configs]
    [webpack, ts and other config files]
```

The issue is, when using `npm run package`, the resulting package contains all the files and directories in the project. I tried using the config to ignore everything I don't need, but seeing the amount of thing I have to specify, and the fact that I would have to update the ignore list everytime a new config file appears in the future, there has to be a better way.

Is there an issue with my project structure ? This is the first time I attempt a project on this scale, any advice would be appreciated !